# unable to run two and more commands in a sequence using subprocess.call

Tags: python, subprocess

Is there any way to execute shell commands in the terminal using python after the

```
google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=\"/usr/local/xxx/coding/ProjectEnvVS\"
```

when I execute the above with subprocess.run, i am getting the below in  the terminal and the script stop executing the next lines of code until the webbrowser is closed manually..

basically, the os.system('python ipdb.py') is not being executed, I have also tried to run subprocess.run commands but noting is being executed.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/bdsss971-xxxx-1111-a105-78ac9a33tttttt
```

t

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import webbrowser
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
import os

def myfunc():


    myCmd = 'google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=\"/usr/local/xxx/coding/ProjectEnvVS\"'
    print (myCmd)

    subprocess.call(myCmd,shell=True)
    os.system('python ipdb.py')
```

Comment: The [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) documentation states that the function waits for the command to complete. This means that as long as the command is running (the chrome window is open), the call blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subprocess.call` is a blocking call. If you want to execute two concurrent calls, use `Popen` instead.